# Creating a working copy for Plone 4 custom content types

Tags: workflow, plone

I have created a custom Plone content type in my package i.e. `my.product`.

I am in need of integrating a working copy support: so that a "published" document (in my case, a published content type) stays online while it is being edited. Basically, I want to take advantage of 'Working Copy Support (Iterate)' provided by [plone.app.iterate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.iterate) to achieve [what is explained here](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-4-user-manual/managing-content/working-copy). This will provide me with ability to `check-in`/`check-out` my changes.

Is this possible in Plone 4 with custom content types using Archetypes? How would one go about it if yes?

Comment: Custom archetype types are no different from the stock types; this should Just Work™.

Comment: In my case it does not. I have added a Page and I can clearly see the option under the Actions dropdown list. But not on my custom type. I can see there is a work around for Dexterity types ( [see here](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.stagingbehavior) ) and I wonder if the same applies to custom types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following two files inside `my.product/my/product/profiles/default` folder and it appears to work:

diff_tool.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object>
    <difftypes>
        <type portal_type="MyCustomType">
            <field name="any" difftype="Compound Diff for AT types"/>
        </type>
    </difftypes>
</object>
```

repositorytool.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<repositorytool>
    <policymap>
        <type name="MyCustomType">
            <policy name="at_edit_autoversion"/>
            <policy name="version_on_revert"/>
        </type>
    </policymap>
</repositorytool>
```

Comment: This can also be configured TTW via the Types control panel.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used plone.app.iterate, but this is the generic approach how to solve the problem.

Actions are installed by *plone.app.iterate* GenericSetup profile. You can see actions here:

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.iterate/blob/master/plone/app/iterate/profiles/default/actions.xml

Pay note to the line *available_expr* which tells when to show the action or not. It points to helper view with the conditition.

The view is defined here

- https://github.com/plone/plone.app.iterate/blob/master/plone/app/iterate/browser/configure.zcml#L7

The checks that are performed for the content item if it's archiveable

- https://github.com/plone/plone.app.iterate/blob/master/plone/app/iterate/browser/control.py#L47

Most likely the failure comes from `if not interfaces.IIterateAware.providedBy` condition. Your custom contennt must declare this interface. However, you can confirm this putting a pdb breakpoint in `checkin_allowed(self)` and step it though line-by-line and see what happens with your content type.